# Importing variable from dependency after compiling

Tags: python-3.x

How can I re-import dependencies when running an executable file after compiling Python script, and not have them being written into it when compiling?

MRE.py

```
from MRE_vars import x, y

print(x * y)
```

MRE_vars.py

```
x = 5
y = 2
```

Works and changes just fine when running from IDE, but is not affected by changes to `MRE_vars.py` after compiling with `pyinstaller --onefile MRE.py`
I know I can easily do this by switching `MRE_vars.py` to `txt` and then evaluating this but how do I do this for `py`? Like if value is not a simple int but depends on user input, or something else in runtime etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile your python code, so the **compiled file is not modified afterwards** (because it is not recompiled like the IDE).

In this case it is possible to use data formats that do not need to be compiled *(JSON, TXT)*. You can try to use a database, if it makes sense in your application